# How to automatically update readme on each new release

Tags: github, github-actions

Currently, when I have a new release on a GitHub repo, I need to update all the readme with the new tag.

Example of readme.md (version 1.0.0):

```
My Java library project

You need to add
`implementation io.github.me:javalib:1.0.0`
```

And I update the readme to (version 2.0.0):

```
My Java library project

You need to add
`implementation io.github.me:javalib:2.0.0`
```

But this manual update is fastidious and sometimes I forgot some tag when I update the documentation.

How can we can automate that?

Comment: When you say "update the readme" do you talk about commit or pull request?

Comment: @ThrowsError Yes

Answer (score 2):

You can automatize that with a GitHub Action like this:

### Requirements

You need to give permission to your GitHub Actions to create a pull request in your GitHub repo settings *(Settings -> Actions -> General)*.

### GitHub Actions examples

These GitHub Actions get automatically the tag of the new release and update your readme with the old tag with the new tag.

#### Update the readme with a pull request

```yaml
name: Update files

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Update files
        uses: MathieuSoysal/file-updater-for-release@v1.0.1
        with:
          files: README.md # List of files to update
          prefix: "io.github.me:javalib:" # Prefix before the version in your cas is io.github.me:javalib:

      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v4
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # You need to create your own token with pull request rights
          commit-message: update readme
          title: Update readme
          body: Update readme to reflect release changes
          branch: update-readme
          base: main
```

#### Update the readme directly with a commit

```yaml
name: Update files with commit

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # You need to create your own token with commit rights
          ref: main # The branch you want to commit to


      - name: Update files
        uses: MathieuSoysal/file-updater-for-release@v1.0.1
        with:
          files: README.md # List of files to update
          prefix: "io.github.me:javalib:" # Prefix before the version in your cas is io.github.me:javalib:
          with-checkout: false # If you don't want to checkout the repo, default is: true
      
      - name: Push changes
        uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v9
        with:
          committer_name: GitHub Actions
          committer_email: actions@github.com
          add: .
          message: 'update files'
```

#### Source

[file-updater-for-release](https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/file-updater-for-release)